# Create a directory in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose yml that creates a sftp image on my docker. I'd like to write a script in the yml file as I want directories to be created automatically as soon as I run the docker-compose.yml.

Here's my yml file;

```
sftp:
  image: atmoz/sftp
  volumes:
    - C:\tmp\sftp:/home/foo/upload
  ports:
    - "2222:22"
  command: username:password:1001
```

Is there a way to write `mkdir` and `chmod` in this file?

Comment: mkdir and chmod for what ?

Comment: @LinPy In order to create a directory after I run docker-compose up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to create and set mod manually, just pass the directory name to `CMD` and the entrypoint will create one for you. Here is the simplest example.

> Define users in (1) `command arguments`, (2) `SFTP_USERS` environment
>   variable or (3) in file mounted as `/etc/sftp/users.conf` (syntax:
>   `user:pass[:e][:uid[:gid[:dir1[,dir2]...]]] ...`, see below for
>   examples)

using docker-compose

```
sftp:
  image: atmoz/sftp
  command: username:password:100:100:upload
```

it will create user name `username` and directory **upload** under `/home/username`
You can verify this using

```
docker exec -it --user username <container_id> bash -c "ls /home/username"
```

if you want to access upload files from host just add mounting in your docker-compose

```
sftp:
  image: atmoz/sftp
  command: username:password:100:100:upload
  volumes:
        - /host/upload:/home/username/upload
```

**Examples**

Simplest docker run example

```
docker run -p 22:22 -d atmoz/sftp foo:pass:::upload
```

> User "foo" with password "pass" can login with sftp and upload files
>   to a folder called "upload". No mounted directories or custom UID/GID.
>   Later you can inspect the files and use --volumes-from to mount them
>   somewhere else (or see next example).

see the [offical documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp)

Comment: Is it possible to create other directories like upload folder with that way?

Comment: from the documentation it seems like you can, you can try with `user:pass[:e][:uid[:gid[:dir1[,dir2]...]]] ` from doc "Directory names at the end will be created under user's home directory with write permission, if they aren't already present"

Comment: @Burak How you created directories in that manner? can you provide that example?